# Delete speicific data in a column in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia to analyze my data, I have some outliers in my data so I want to delete them; there is some data; e.g. numbers above 75; I want to exclude them. 
for example, using DataFrames.jl, df is a dataset``:

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"])
```

How can I delete 1 in column A

What is the best code to do so?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using to load/create the data and what exactly you want to achieve. If we know in what format you store the data it is possible to give you a recommendation. Most likely you are using DataFrames.jl, in which case I recommend you to read https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/latest/ and https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial.

Comment: I edited my question, Thank you, Bogumil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is in a vector, you can use filter:

```
julia> data = rand(collect(1:100), 30); println(data);
[82, 80, 63, 6, 39, 44, 80, 80, 83, 58, 68, 87, 49, 40, 19, 87, 48, 19, 4, 80, 51, 
82, 37, 2, 74, 90, 19, 68, 47, 11]

julia> filtered = filter(x -> x < 75, data); println(filtered);
[63, 6, 39, 44, 58, 68, 49, 40, 19, 48, 19, 4, 51, 37, 2, 74, 19, 68, 47, 11]
```

If the data is in a dataframe, you can filter rows on column values:

```
julia>  df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"])
4×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B      │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ M      │   
│ 2   │ 2     │ F      │
│ 3   │ 3     │ F      │
│ 4   │ 4     │ M      │

julia> df2 = filter(x -> x.A != 1, df)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B      │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ F      │
│ 2   │ 3     │ F      │
│ 3   │ 4     │ M      │
```

Comment: Thank you, Bill! but after filtration, how can I delete them, I don't want the data outliers.

Comment: see revised answer --  you can use filter on a dataframe to filter for certain rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
julia> df = df[df.A .!= 1, :]
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B      │
│     │ Int64 │ String │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 2     │ F      │
│ 2   │ 3     │ F      │
│ 3   │ 4     │ M      │
```

The `.` before `!=` is used to vectorize the operation and the `:` is used for returning all the columns. If you want to additionally filter on columns too, you can pass the vector of columns you want instead of `:`